# Why is this object not callable? the object is the item or the list?

Tags: python

I want to print an item in a list via a function, but it says

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

here is my code:

```
list = ['oi', 'hi', 'hello']
def print_item(index):
    print(list(index))
```

the expected output is that it prints the item acording to the index

Answer (score 1):

In python `()` after a word is to call/execute a function. And `[]` is used to select items within a collection.

If you need to select the element in the **`index`** position you have to do **`list [index]`**.